# Why won't trailing newline character (\n) show empty line in content editable div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I have a content editable div with `pre-wrap` style. (I wanted easy text manipulation and didn't want to struggle with `<br>` for line break while transferring text to and from the div.)

When a string like `1\n2\n3` is given, it shows as expected. However, if there is a `\n` at the end, an empty line isn't shown. So, when a user presses enter after the last character, although the `\n` is added to the text, the empty line cue isn't shown (it does show when hitting enter twice though, but I don't want that.)

How to get it to show?

I am using Firefox 42 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't quite get an answer to this problem (not just on SO but even in my research). However, I found a hack to get around this. Using one of the non breaking spaces characters gives me what I want. I don't intend to pass the data to third party processing, so whatever character I choose can be removed in post processing.

Comment: U+2060 WORD JOINER (HTML &#8288; · WJ) - good character, it's invisible and does the djob

Comment: This way you would need to press backspace twice to delete the line, right?